# What is the earliest known occurrence of woven rope mats / art?

Tags: art, age-of-sail

I am curious as to the earliest recorded occurrence of woven rope mats such as the one below:
[image: Ocean Plait Rope Mat]

Similar patterns can be seen in Celtic knotwork and the Insular art style in the 600's+. But I was wondering about the crossover to fiber art.

Obviously rope isn't the best material for preservation, but I thought I'd throw it out there.

The practice is most commonly known for its use in the 1700's+.